# ExtJS Roles and Rights Concept

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an app with roles and rights system. Basically I need to show and hide things depending on the role and rights settings.

For example I have a grid which have static fields (visible for all users regardless of role and right property):

```
var grid_results_columns = [
    { text: 'CompanyName', dataIndex: 'CompanyName', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Address', dataIndex: 'Address', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'System ID', dataIndex: 'SID', flex: 1 }
];
```

And if I want to show/hide a column I do it like this:

```
if (settings.rights[0].HasShowAdminColumn) {
    grid_results_columns.push({ text: 'AdminSetting', dataIndex: 'AdminSetting' });
}
```

The `settings` is JSON that I get from backend using AJAX. It has array of rights and one of array elements is `HasShowAdminColumn` which can be true or false (1 or 0).

There are so many roles and rights and grids that has to be modified. Is there any automated process to handle this more easier and less painful? Otherwise I am ending up with thousand of lines of code where I would have to check every role and right and push the columns based on rights status.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS you are using ?

Comment: ExtJS 6, but without CMD.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a bind to hidden on the column. You could load the settings on the main viewmodel data property, and inherit it all the way down. Or you can create settings configs in children components, bind them to outter viewmodel explicitly, and on the update hook set it up into internal viewmodel

```
Ext.define('MyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'MyGrid',
    viewModel: {
    },
    store: {
        data: [{
            name: 'Foo',
            admin: 'Admin foo'
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'name'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'admin',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'admin',
        hidden: true,
        bind: {
            hidden: '{!rights.showAdmin}'
        }
    }]
});

Ext.define('Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    viewModel: {
        rights: {}
    },

    controller: {
        init: function() {
            var vm = this.getViewModel();
            //mimick ajax load
            setTimeout(function(){
                vm.set('rights', {showAdmin: true});
            },3000);
        }
    },

    layout: 'fit',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'MyGrid'
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Main', {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```